# Java Open a Web Browser to a URI with an HTTP GET Request

Tags: java, http, get

I am writing a Java desktop application that uses the `last.fm` API to download data. I am stuck on the authentication process where the instruction is to:

Open a web browser and send the user to `last.fm/api/auth` with your API key and auth token as parameters. Use an HTTP `GET` request.

I do not understand how to open a web browser to a specific URI using an HTTP GET request. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&token=yyyyyy"));
```

According to `last.fm` [documentation](https://www.last.fm/api/authspec):

> If the user is not logged in to Last.fm, they will be redirected to the login page before being asked to grant your application permission to use their account. On this page they will see the name of your application, along with the application description and logo as supplied in Section 2. Once the user has granted your application permission to use their account, the browser-based process is over and the user is asked to close their browser and return to your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried this code and it does open the web browser and ask for the user authorization, but it doesn't seem to link up my application with the user account (checked in user account Settings). Is this the same as using a GET request to open the browser and ask for the authorization?

Comment: Check if you are passing the correct `api_key` and `token` values. You should get the the token via `auth.getToken`. The approach is the same as asking the user to copy link from your application and paste it into a browser. But it is not the same as you silently make a GET request via [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/httpclient5/apidocs/index.html) for example.

Comment: I tested the values for the api_key and token and they look good. Thanks for the explanation on the difference between using the Desktop object and the HTTP client. I am still receiving the 403 response code.